# Delete the last row of a table - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I delete the last row of a table based (if it will have a changing length)?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

x = 1:10
y =11:20

lastrow = length(x);
t = table(x,y)
 
t([lastrow,:) = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `end` function to access the last row or column.

I think you wanted to create a `10 by 2` table. If you want to do so, you should define `x` and `y` as a column vector, not a row vector.

```matlab
clc;
clear all;
close all;

x = (1:10)';
y =(11:20)';

% lastrow = length(x);
t = table(x,y);
 
t(end,:) = [];
disp(t)
```

[image: output]